# Quali sono le differenze tra "corso" e "percorso"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

In un testo di grammatica italiana, che sto leggendo, la parola "corso" è usata nelle introduzioni alle sezioni, mentre in qualsiasi altro posto, la parola "percorso" è usata. C'è una differenza?

Comment: Sì, sono due parole diverse con significati diversi, un po' come “mela” e “carciofo”, che per caso compaiono nello stesso libro. Hai cercato su un vocabolario?

Comment: Sì, quando ho cercato il dizionario, mi sembra che entrambi significano "course" (nell'inglese). Non è corretto? Aiuterebbe se ho postato il contesto per entrambi?

Comment: Ah, ho capito da dove proviene la tua confusione. Se puoi, usa un vocabolario monolingue solo italiano, ma intanto rispondo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

“Corso” e “percorso” sono due parole diverse con significati diversi (anche se condividono parte dell'etimologia, dal latino *cursus*).

Il significato di “corso” nel tuo libro è quello di “serie di lezioni”, che complessivamente insegnano qualcosa. Quindi si parla di “corso di italiano” o di “corso di studi universitari” e così via. (Un “corso” può essere anche una via importante all'interno di una città.)

Un “percorso” è un cammino, un itinerario, sia in senso letterale (per andare da un punto X a un punto Y), sia in senso figurato (un insieme di esperienze, di letture, di riflessioni da compiere per arrivare a un certo risultato). Nel tuo libro, immagino, lo usano per parlare della “strada” da fare per imparare una lingua.

La tua confusione, evidentemente, viene dal fatto che in inglese *course* può avere entrambi i significati. Consiglio di fare un minimo di fatica in più e, in casi così, di consultare un vocabolario italiano monolingue.

Comment: Grazie per la tua risposta. Otterrò un dizionario italiano per la prossima volta. Spiacente! Chiaramente, un inglese-italiano dizionario non è abbastanza.